# Find k - smallest element (Java code)

Tags: java, arrays

I want to solve the following problem: Given an unsorted array of n elements, find the first k smallest elements. To do this I want to build a max heap of size k (from the last k elements of the array) and then to scan the rest of the elements in the array. If I find a smaller element than my root element I exchange both elements and then I heapify my heap. This solution should works in O(nlogk) time and in place. However I cannot fix it (I have index out of bound exception). I tried to debug it but I don't see where is my mistake. This is my code:

```
public class KSmallest {
    private static int[] a;
    private static int n;

    public static void buildheap(int []a){
        n=a.length-1;
        for(int i=n;i>=0;i--){
            maxheap(a,i);
        }
        for (int i = n-1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if(a[i]<a[start]){
                exchange(i, 0);
                maxheap(a, 0);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void exchange(int i, int j){
        int t=a[i];
        a[i]=a[j];
        a[j]=t;
    }

    public static void sort(int []a0){
        a=a0;
        for(int i=n; i>0; i--){
            exchange(0, i);
            n=n-1;
            maxheap(a, 0);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int []a1={4,1,3,2,7, 2, 1, 4};
        int start = a1.length-k;
        for(int i=start;i<a1.length;i++){
            System.out.print(a1[i] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
        //sort(a1);
        for(int i=start;i<a1.length;i++){
            System.out.print(a1[i] + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

I'm struggling with this for two days so I hope anyone can help.

Comment: Where is your exception?

Comment: One of the better things you can do for these kinds of situations is pull out a pencil and piece of paper, make up a small test case, then perform your assigned task on the paper while using the debugger to make the program mirror what you are doing. When what you're doing diverges from the program's execution, that's a place where you might have made a mistake.

Comment: It that's not an education task, you should consider using `SortedSet` (implemented as, for example, TreeSet), if it's educational, you should try to teach yourself using debugger or print-debugging (or, as it was said before, pencil and the piece of paper).

Comment: You should add the stacktrace with the exception

Comment: Assuming it is a class project (and swapping out with a java.util class isn't an option), consider putting your Heap in a class.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a learning exercise, so feel free to ignore this answer. But if anyone ever needs to do this in the real world, you'd use this n*log(n) solution.

```
public static Collection<Integer> findKSmallest(Collection<Integer> data, int k) {
    assert k > 0;
    assert k <= data.size();
    ArrayList<Integer> dataAsList = new ArrayList<Integer>(data);
    Collections.sort(dataAsList);
    return dataAsList.subList(0, k);
}
```

Comment: Well, he is looking for k smallest elements, not a k-th smallest element.

Answer (score 1):

First thing to notice are the variable names that aren't very meaningful...'a', 'a0', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'n', 't', as well as the mutable static variables which are always a nightmare to work with.

Anyway I ran the code and got a NullPointerException in the exchange() method.

What's happening is the buildheap() method has a parameter called 'a' which is the same name used for a class variable, so when it's passing 'a' to maxheap() then exhange(), it's passing the class variable rather than the parameter.

Try adding this line as the first line in the buildheap() method:

```
KSmallest.a = a;
```

**Edit**
I'm not sure whether that will actually work or not, but it prevents the NPE.

Using meaningful names for all variables like you used with 'left, 'right' 'largest' etc. will be of great help, a few extra characters doesn't waste trees!

Also try to avoid mutable static variables too. Either keep them as constants by using the 'final' keyword, and - by convention - make them all caps. Or use instance variables instead and remove the static keywords, that's the more OOP paradigm.

Anyway good luck! :)

Answer (score 1):

Writing the heap data strucutre is a good practice. I am using priority queue which is readily available min Heap in java. for this problem I need a max heap so I am using a Comparator to create a max heap.

```
public class KLowestElements {

/*comparator to create max heap*/
static class MaxHeapComparator implements Comparator<Integer> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Integer a, Integer b) {
        return b.compareTo(a);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //sample input
    int[] input = { 11, 2, 23, 34, 5};

    // heap size
    int k = 3;
    MaxHeapComparator maxHeapComparator = new MaxHeapComparator();
    PriorityQueue<Integer> maxHeap = new PriorityQueue<>(k,
            maxHeapComparator);

     //Loop Invariant: If heap size is k, compare top element with next 
     //element in the array. If element is smaller than the top element, 
     //remove the top integer and insert element from array. 
     for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        if (maxHeap.size() < k) {
            maxHeap.add(input[i]);
        } else if (maxHeap.peek() > input[i]) {
            maxHeap.remove();
            maxHeap.add(input[i]);
        }
    }

    //print values 
    for (int i : maxHeap) {
        System.out.print(i + " ");
    }
}
}
```